# Can 8-3 wire be used with a 10-50R 3 wire receptacle?

Tags: electrical

I renovated my house with my father-in-law.  We removed a wall and had to relocate the receptacle for the electric stove range. He had me buy 8-3 wire, and we ran this wire from the breaker box to the new range location.  Consequently, we also bought a new range.

However, he connected the 8-3 supply wire to a 3 prong 10-50R receptacle that he had lying around. I just got curious and was reading and it seems that when you run a new 8-3 supply wire you are supposed to connect it to a 4 prong receptacle.

I didn't see how he hooked up, but the range works fine and we have been using it for months now.  I am just wondering if it is fine what he did or if I should change out the 3 prong receptacle with the 4 prong receptacle and buy a 4 prong power cord.

Comment: Some cook tops do not require a 4 prong receptacle.  If you can post the make and model, we can verify this.

Comment: Yes, illegal.  You're not allowed to use a 10-50 in new work.  The only reason the store sells them is for receptacle replacements only.  They are banned because they are dangerous.  If there is any problem with your neutral wire, it will energize the stove's chassis at 120VAC which in a kitchen is likely to cause an electrocution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A NEMA 10-50R device does not have a grounding pin, so your father-in-law likely simply didn't connect the grounding conductor from the cable. A NEMA 14-50R, which should have been used, does have a grounding pin.

Technically, you should have installed a 14-50 receptacle in the first place (to be code compliant). That being said. Loads of old homes have 10-50R devices in place, and have worked fine that way for many years. As it's currently wired, the range should continue to function without a problem. However, without a proper ground, there's always the potential for electric shock. It's up to you, whether or not you think the potential dangers are great enough to take action.

Comment: I have see many where the ground is jumped to the neutral. But Tester is absolutely right, change the receptacle to the newest proper one that fits your need. Most ranges do not come with a cord and must be purchased separately, so buy the 4 prong plug/cord.